# Facebook share html code

Tags: c#, facebook

I have the following code in my razor template

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Model.Url" target="_blank">
    <img src="~/Static/Images/facebook-final.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

I want to include title, description as well.

I have added these og tags in the _Root.cshtml file

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
```

But when I click on share it doesn't pick any of these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, Facebook will visit your page (the page link in the share button) in order to parse the OpenGraph data.

This means that it will not read this data if you're working locally.